# Fatal error: Call to undefined function win32_query_service_status()

Tags: apache-2.2, php, installation

I want to configure PHP with Apache 2.2 server. But I am getting error when tried to call php_win32service.dll.
php_win32service.dll present in C:\Program Files\PHP\ext folder.
I am using win32_query_Service_status function in .php file.
Error:-
Fatal error: Call to undefined function win32_query_Service_status().

Comment: Did you declare the extension in the php.ini ?

Comment: Yes..extension=php_win32service.dll

Answer (score 1):

Very Old Question, but I just had this problem with PHP 8.1 on Windows w/IIS and didn't find any good answers.

My problem was a mismatch between NTS and TS versions of php.exe and the extension dll.

- PHP 8.1 was NTS (Not Thread Safe)
- php_win32service.dll was TS (Thread Safe)

Solution: Pick either NTS or TS